# An issue in using while loop with multiple conditions

Tags: java

I have the following Java while loop:

```
    boolean finish = false;
    int ii = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while((!finish) || (counter <= 10)) {
        ii++;
        if(ii<30) {
            System.out.println(ii + " -- " + counter);
        }else {
            finish=true;
        }
        counter++;
    }
```

I want the loop to add one to `ii` until it reaches 30 or the `counter` reaches 10. Running this code ignores the condition of counter and continues until `ii` reaches 30. I expect it to stop when `counter` reaches 10.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change while((!finish) || (counter <= 10))
to 
while((!finish) && (counter <= 10))

and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

It should be &&, not ||, since you want the loop to loop as long as both ii<30 AND counter<=10.